# Spacing 5 div tag , each has a background image

Tags: html, css, alignment, spacing

I got several `div` tag , and wanted to juxtapose them in a single line , all of those `div` have a `background` attribute.

Without `ul` and `li` tags , is there any other way to finish this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` and `li` tags are not in a single line either. what you mean is the css-attribute `float`!